# Ubuntu Server on 80GB disk; root partition is too small

Tags: boot

Note that I don't have physical access to the server.

However I can use WinSCP or WEBmin.

I use Linux kernel 4.10.0-35-generic; Ubuntu 16.

My HDD of 80GB (root) is even to small to update some packages.

```
root@WeBuntu:~# sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 74,5 GiB, 80000000000 bytes, 156250000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000a598c

Apparaat   Op.  Start     Einde  Sectoren  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048    499711    497664  243M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2      501758 156248063 155746306 74,3G  5 uitgebreid
/dev/sda5      501760 156248063 155746304 74,3G 8e Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/WeBuntu--vg-root: 73,2 GiB, 78626422784 bytes, 153567232 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/WeBuntu--vg-swap_1: 1020 MiB, 1069547520 bytes, 2088960 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

How can I make space? Let me know if you need any further information and I will post it.

```
ivan@WeBuntu:~$ df -h
Bestandssysteem              Grootte Gebruikt Besch Geb% Aangekoppeld op
udev                            474M        0  474M   0% /dev
tmpfs                            99M      12M   88M  12% /run
/dev/mapper/WeBuntu--vg-root     72G      18G   51G  27% /
tmpfs                           495M        0  495M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                           5,0M        0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                           495M        0  495M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                       236M     236M     0 100% /boot
tmpfs                            99M        0   99M   0% /run/user/1000
```

---

```
ivan@WeBuntu:~$ mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=484924k,nr_inodes=121231,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=101268k,mode=755)
/dev/mapper/WeBuntu--vg-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=34,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=1999)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw,relatime,block_validity,barrier,user_xattr,acl)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=101264k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
```

Comment: Please update your post with output of command `df -h` (total, free and used space) and `mount`.

Comment: How do I repley correctly on a remark of an other user/specialist?
I dont find sommething as "Repley" ..

Answer (score 0):

According to your output of `df -h` you have not problems with size of `/` (root filesystem).

```
Filesystem                      Size     Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/WeBuntu--vg-root     72G      18G   51G  27% /
/dev/sda1                       236M     236M     0 100% /boot
```

You have 0 free bytes on `/boot` and it is a problem.

Install Byobu package with `sudo apt-get install byobu` and run `sudo purge-old-kernels && sudo apt-get autoremove`.

Comment: Will APT be able to install anything in this situation?

Comment: OP has space in rootfs, so I think it is able. But for now I can't understand which problems he have.

Comment: Well, as I'm far a way from my server, I have to do everything via SSH. Now, yesterday I moved a backup file from the server toward myPC here. Both action failed. result, server doesn't start anymore, and Backup stopped somwhere in the middle. Bref, I have to wait until I'm Home. Anyway, thanks. I just hope I did'nt losa any data, cross fingers.